# How to Create line item Grid with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html

The figure below was created with React to add and remove line items. But I need to create with AngularJS and Html of course. Please I need some help implementing this with AngularJS.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: share your code how you tried so far. No one is gonna write from scratch for you

Comment: @tanmay if pure html would be enough, I can provide that.

Comment: you must have some angular module written and try to use `ng-repeat` to render the list. Write that and share some of your code

Comment: @tanmay let me see what I can do about that. I'll respond within the hour as in on my way to work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try nggrid to create grid, CRUD operations are very simple in this

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/